# Add tilde to sqlalchemy filter based on boolean flag

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking for a Pythonic way to write below code:

```
filters = []
flag = True
if flag:
    filters.append(Model.name=='some_name')
else:
    filters.append(~Model.name=='some_name')
```

So the questions is actually if I can make above `if else` statement one liner using flag for appending tilde.

Comment: I honestly don't think it really gets much better than this.  There might be shorter ways to write it, but none of them as clear and simple as this.

Comment: I agree with @mgilson.. My answer is certainly a one-liner solution, but python ternary operators are pretty wordy by nature.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

`filters.append(Model.name=='some_name' if flag else ~Model.name=='some_name')`